# Good string compression algorithms/approaches for list of small strings?

Tags: string, algorithm, compression

I have a list of small strings, and I would like to quickly compress them. What is a good approach to do this? The strings don't have any other properties, aside from having ~13 million strings with sizes from 5 - 30 characters length.

Update: From the comments, these are sent over a network, used for a join so I don't know the specific properties, order doesn't matter, and I am sending them in bulk.

Comment: Strings of what? Lower-case English words? Mixed case? Random alphanumeric characters? Random 8-bit bytes?

Comment: Have a look at [Huffman Encoding](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-3-huffman-coding/).

Comment: If they really don't have any other properties, then they're totally random, and nothing will work.  If they have at least some nonrandomness, then probably a fast general-purpose compressor like gzip will find most of it.  You also don't say if you care about the order of the strings; if you don't, you might be able to save a bit more space with a good ordering (e.g. lexicographical will at least tend to put strings with the same prefix near each other).

Comment: If you don't have any operations you need the compressed form for, you can semi-instantaneously compress them to *zero* memory occupancy by just deleting them: state what the compressed form shall be useful for. Not *knowing* properties of input data before processing is (luckily) different from lack thereof.

Comment: In addition to answered the "Strings of what?" question, what do you want to do with the compressed data? Do you just need to reconstruct the whole list? In order? Do you need to access strings randomly?

Comment: It can be totally random. My goal is to compress them, send them over a network, and then decompress them. The order doesn't matter when I get them back, I can just bulk decompress them in order. I just need to transfer data in as compressed fashion as possible.

Comment: This is used for a distributed join, so the actual field types will generally be non-random, but I can't predict on what types of fields users will be joining on. So it could be English words, IDs and other properties. That's why I thought a standard compressor like gzip would be a good fit.

Comment: Don't comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your question. Especially for essential information like `send them over a network`, `bulk decompress` or `[decompressed] order doesn't matter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, you don't need to be able to decompress an individual `small string`.
Sorting the strings prior to using the standard compression/decompression method you can most easily use should go a long way.
Measure the difference in effect, report welcome!

`as compressed as possible` is dangerous as any "optimisation".
*Fix* a goal upfront and a way to tell *not there* from *good enough*, and move on once achieved.